# Why is $f(x,y) := 6y+4x-x^3y$ infinitely often continuously partially differentiable?

Tags: calculus, derivatives, continuity, hessian-matrix

Let $f: \mathbb{R^2} \to \mathbb{R}$ with $f(x,y) := 6y+4x-x^3y$

How can one argue that $f$ is infinitely often continuously partially differentiable?

I also calculated the gradient $\nabla f: \mathbb{R^2} \to \mathbb{R^2}$ and got

$\nabla f = (4-3yx^2, 6-x^3)$

The Hessian matrix $H_f: \mathbb{R^2} \to \mathbb{R}^{2 × 2}$ is

$H_f = \begin{pmatrix} -6yx& -3x^2 \\ -3x^2& 0 \end{pmatrix}$

Can someone confirm that and the question above? Thanks!

Comment: I agree with your computations. What do you mean "infinitely often continuously partially differentiable"? Do you mean $\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x}$ and $\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial y}$ exist and are continuous on an infinite set? Do you mean that $\dfrac{\partial^{n+m} f}{\partial x^n \partial x^m}$ exists everywhere for all $n, m$? I'm not certain what you're trying to show, in particular.

Comment: @TheoBendit Thanks Theo. It was an exam question and there are no further info. I think it's asking why we can keep taking the partial derivates forever, for example $f_x$, $f_{xx}$, $f_{xxx}$ etc.

Comment: Ah, so that'd be my second interpretation. The answer would be to point out that $f$ is a polynomial, that every polynomial is continuously partially differentiable (everywhere), and that any partial derivative of a polynomial is a polynomial.

Comment: @TheoBendit Makes sense. Thanks!

Comment: If you calculate the partial derivative of $f(x,y)$ w.r.t $y$ the variable $x$ is treated as a constant. Thus we can replace $x$ by $c_1$ and $x^3$ by $c_2$:

$f(y)=(6-c_2)y+c_1$

This is a linear function.  The second derivative is 0 and therefore all succeeding derivatives.